# Has the wall been repaired?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* season 7, we saw the Night King's army destroy (at least part of) the Wall. At the end of S08E06, we see Jon go

> north of the Wall.

In those final shots, the Wall seems to be intact. Has it been repaired? Why is there no visible damage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Has it been repaired? Why is there no visible damage?

### No, the Wall most likely hasn't been repaired [yet].

The Wall is pretty long, about 300 miles. When the Night King breached the Wall, he did so at Eastwatch-by-the-sea (just labeled Eastwatch on the map below). The shots we see of Jon Snow at the Wall in S08E06 is at Castle Black, where Tormund told Jon Snow he would take the wildlings back to once the winter storms passed, in S08E04.

[image]

Comment: is there any reason to repair it?

Comment: @AlecA apart from an OCD, no.

Comment: Also, as you can see, the wall stop at shadow tower, with a whole gap (the gorge) between the wall and bay of ice.

Comment: @AlecA, Night watch is an incredibly usefull thing. I guess we can keep the guys bussy for few century.